# What is the XPT protocol?

Tags: protocol, primecoin

XPT (x.pushthrough) is used by some mining pools (e.g. ypool.net, primecoin). I have googled but could not find any reference to the details of this protocol. What is the protocol to be able to write a basic client?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that XPT protocol was developed by ypool.net and there is no official specification of it.
But it is possible to get details from the source code of [xptMiner](https://github.com/jh000/xptMiner) or [xptProxy](https://github.com/jh000/xptProxy).

You can start from https://github.com/jh000/xptProxy/blob/master/src/xptProxy/xptClient.cpp